# how to use cmdscale function in matlab to represent 2 dimension?

Tags: matlab, matrix, multidimensional-array, dimension

i want to use Multidimensional Scaling by cmdscaling in matlab.
input was dissimilarity matrix 3*3 such as
0 3 5
3 0 4
5 4 0  = d
then, i use this input by cmdsclae as
y=cmdscale(d)
however, the output was 3*1 matrix, so i could not represent this matrix on 2 dimensional space.
this is because my code works by 2 inputs as x and y axis.
text(y(:,1), y(:,2), labels);
i want to know why this function cannot make more than 1 column as output

i tried as y=cmdscale(d,2), but it didnt add additional column for output